# CGI in a ruby sinatra server

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cgi

I am develop a simple web app with sinatra and ruby, and I have two files: `app.rb` is my sinatra app and `test.cgi` is a CGI program. I need execute the CGI script, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
# app.rb

require "sinatra"

get "/form" do
    File.read("my_web_form.html")
end

post "/form" do
    # I need execute the CGI script, but this not works:
    cgi "text.cgi"
end
```

My CGI script is a custom language (I have a interpreter created by me), and I try to embed it into web apps. Thanks.

Comment: *In what way* does it not work? We can't help solve your problem if you don't tell us what the problem is. Please edit your question to include as much detail as you can.

Comment: You don't need a CGI program with Sinatra. Write the code as a `get` or `post` handler. The Sinatra home page explains it nicely. CGI is *very* old school.

Comment: CGI is incredibly outdated. Any reason you are using that?

Comment: I have a program enviroment thats not have support for a bundled module in the Apache 2 sever, but works right using CGI. Because this, I can't use Apache 2 and I try to use ruby and sinatra, but bundled with CGI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some searching and I'm not able to find a way to "render CGI" in the way you're trying (which is the intuitive way).

However it does seem that you can run Sinata *from* a CGI. See [here](https://gist.github.com/rkitover/5144687) for a code example.

I was actually trying to do this a few days ago, and I guess I gave up. But seeing your question encouraged me to figure it out. See the following example of how to render CGI from sinatra:

*A sample CGI file, say it's at `./app.cgi` and `chmod +x` has been run*

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "cgi"
cgi = CGI.new("html4")
cgi.out{
   cgi.html{
      cgi.head{ "\n"+cgi.title{"This Is a Test"} } +
      cgi.body{ "\n"+
        cgi.h1 { "This is a Test" } + "\n"+
      }

   }
}
```

*A module which defines a `render_cgi` method*:

```
class RenderCgiError < StandardError
end

module RenderCgi

  def render_cgi(filepath, options={})
    headers_string, body = run_cgi_and_parse_output(filepath, options)
    headers_hash = parse_headers_string(headers_string)
    response = Rack::Response.new
    headers_hash.each { |k,v| response.header[k] = v }
    response.body << body
    response
  end

  private
  def run_cgi_and_parse_output(filepath, options={})
    options_string = options.reduce("") { |str, (k,v)| str << "#{k}=#{v} " }
    # make sure options has at least one key-val pair, otherwise running the CGI may hang
    if options_string.split("=").select { |part| (part&.length || -1) > 0 }.length < 2
      raise(RenderCgiError, "one truthy key and associated truthy val is required for options")
    end
    output = `sh #{filepath} #{options_string}`
    headers_string, body = output.split("\n\r")
    return [headers_string, body]
  end

  def parse_headers_string(string)
    return string.split("\n").reduce({}) do |results, line|
      key, val = line.split(": ")
      results[key.chomp] = val.chomp
      next results
    end
  end
end
```

*and a Sinatra app which runs it*

```
require 'sinatra'
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  include RenderCgi
  get '/' do
    render_cgi("./app.cgi", { "foo" => "bar" })
  end
end
MyApp.run!
```